# My modifiers icon disappeared

Tags: modifiers, interface, shortcut

I am using Blender version 2.81a, my Modifiers icon (the little wrench) disappeared on my tab. How do I get it back?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Some objects cannot have modifiers on them (lights, instances). Are you sure you have a mesh object selected?

Answer (score 1):

Some objects cannot have *Modifiers* on them (lights, empties, instances).
When such objects are selected, the *Modifier Tab (little wrench)* just isn't shown.

[image]